# Not able to add selected value from combobox value as a filter for file search from a folder

Tags: java

I need to get all the files from folder and subfolders of a directory with filter condition received from drop down. For that i used the following method to retrieve file names but not able to add filter in that

```
  public  File[] listf(String directoryName) {

    // .............list file
    File directory = new File(directoryName);

        System.out.println("Pub date+++++++++++++>"+d_publication.getSelectedItem().toString());

    // get all the files from a directory
    File[] fList = directory.listFiles();
        String publishDW = d_publication.getSelectedItem().toString();

    for (File file : fList) {

                    if (file.isFile() && file.getName().contains(publishDW) && file.getName().contains(".xml") ){ 
            // System.out.println("FileName" + file.getName());
                                      fileNameList.addElement(file.getName());
                                      files.add(file);
 } 

                      else if (file.isDirectory()) {
            listf(file.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }

    //System.out.println(fList);
    return fList;
}
```

Without file.getName().contains(publishDW) my code works properly but when i add this filter condition am not getting files as output